# Importing Text into C# results in an unsupported character (shows question mark in triangle)

Tags: c#, .net, io

I have a process which reads text from a text file.  Overall, it works fine, but in one file, the imported char shows as a triangle with a question mark.

What is this, and what do I do about it?

Comment: Which char is it? The first, or a later one?

Comment: Look at neoistheone's answer. You probably need to switch to a different encoding. If you provide code, somebody might give concrete hints.

Comment: I did some code to see the actual character code, and it comes out to 65533

Comment: U+FFFD is the Unicode substitution character.  A diamond, not a triangle.  The text file is not encoded in utf-8, Encoding.Default is the usual next guess.

Comment: @Hans Thank you.  I did not know it is the Unicode substitution character.  The file I am reading is a plan text file. But it came across the wire, and I think the char got corrupted. All the rest can be read just fine.

Comment: Hmm, we don't use telegraphs anymore.  If you know nothing about the file then you can't know the proper encoding to use either.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong encoding. You probably need to use `UTF8` vs. `ASCII`. Now, I have no idea how to help with your code, well because there is no code in the question, but the encoding is your problem.